# redirect stdout and stderr in a bash script

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have the following script (line numbering is for reference):

```
#!/bin/bash

1-  for version in `ls -al ./atk/ | grep ^d | grep -Ev '\.$' | awk -F' ' '{print $8}'`
2-      do
3-          grep $version ./atk/versions #&>/dev/null <--(first ran with this comment out)
4-          if [ $? -ne 0 ]
5-              then
6-                  printf '%-15s\n' "$version"
7-          fi
8-      done
```

if I run it as is, line 1 will send the following to the screen:(I really don't want this, would like stdout/stderr to go to `/dev/null`, but more on this later)

```
aaaaa--------
bbbbb       |
ccccc       |
ddddd       |------------ wil be stored in the version variable
eeeee       |
fffff       |
ggggg--------
```

line 2 will look for `$version` in a "versions" file that contains the following:

```
12345
aaaaa
67890
ccccc
09876
fffff
```

if `$version` is not found in the "versions" file then print $versions to stdout.

output should be the following:

```
bbbbb
ddddd
eeeee
ggggg
```

how do I get line 1 to send its output to `/dev/null` and then have line 3 send
its output back to stdout and stderr?

strangely enough, if I uncomment the end of line 3, everything works fine in spite
of the redirection of stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`!

I tried the following:

```
for version in `ls -al ./atk/ | grep ^d &>/dev/null | grep -Ev '\.$' | awk -F' ' '{print $8}'` &>/dev/null
```

not only did it suppress the output that I didn't want to see from line 1, but also the output from line 3
that I did want to see even after modifying the code as such:

```
for version in `ls -al ./atk/ | grep ^d | grep -Ev '\.$' | awk -F' ' '{print $8}'` &>/dev/null
    do
        exec &>/dev/tty  ++++++++++++++ trying to reset stdout and stderr back to the origal setting
        grep $version ./atk/versions #&>/dev/null
```

again, why does line 3 without the comment work when I'm explicitly asking to send all output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 2):

On line 1 the command in backticks sends its *stdout* to the `for...` loop. It writes nothing to the screen unless there's an error from one of the commands (for example, `ls` might complain about the directory path being missing).

The `grep` on line 3 does write to *stdout*, though. Perhaps you want the `-q` flag for quiet mode.

I'm trying to understand what you're actually trying to do, because I think it can probably be handled much more simply:

```
for item in atk/*
do
    test -d "$item" && echo "${item/*\/}" | grep -Fvf atk/versions
done
```

As an aside, using backticks for command interpolation is no longer considered good coding style. You would be better using the `$( ... )` construct. Such as `for version in $( ls ... awk )`

Comment: thanks roaima, that pointed me in the right direction and revealed what this script is actually doing.

Comment: @linuxbox099 if this answer solved your problem please use the tick mark to accept it